# DHCP , DNS , FTP , what is the best way to run ? dockerize or just simple install on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, docker, ftp, dhcp

I'm going to install DNS and DHCP and simple FTP service on my company network. My network has about 200 clients, what is the best way to install those services? on a docker environment or just simple installation on different 3 ubuntu servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these services, response time is not the greatest concern. You should however think about reliability and image configuration support.

For instance, when a DHCP server restarts, it must recover previous leases to allow clients re-use them. So you must check in the image description which directories are persisted besides configuration `/etc/dhcpd.conf`.

You should also ensure for your business environment that images have solid support/documentation and come from a trusted source. I was not able to find one in the past for DHCP Server.